# Delete Smart Lists from Facebook

Tags: facebook, list

I'd like to remove several "smart lists" from my Facebook account. On the [lists page](https://www.facebook.com/bookmarks/lists), I'm able to remove custom-made lists using the dropdown menu (pencil icon), but smart lists created by Facebook cannot be deleted this way.

Is there a way to remove these lists? I've already removed the associated profile entries from my account (for example, college/university pages), but the smart lists of people who attended them were not removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=200848319959471#How-do-I-delete-a-list?), you can't delete smart lists:

> Note: You can’t delete default lists, but you can hide them from your
>   home page. These lists will also stop appearing on your home page if
>   you don't use them.

You can archive them, so they stop posting things. They will still be accessible through > lists.

Comment: That's a shame. Thank you for your response, though.

Answer (score 0):

If **Facebook**'s built in interface doesn't work to get rid of them, you can hide the links to the Smart Lists from the left column of your newsfeed using **Custom CSS** code, as outlined below

To use Custom CSS, you first need to install a browser add-on such as **FB Purity** ( http://fbpurity.com ), that lets you add your own **CSS** to alter the layout of Facebook's pages.

**1)** Click the link to the "Smart" list that you want to hide and look at the number that shows in the URL in the browser's address bar (its the number after /lists/) Copy that number

**2)** Replace the **XXXXX** in the code below with the number you copied, and paste it into FBP's Custom CSS box, then click "**Save & Close**":

```
/* Hide smart list in left column */
#listsNav div[data-itemid="XXXXX"] {display:none}
```

**3)** After clicking the Save button the page will refresh, and the smart list you chose to hide should be gone. Add a line of code as above for each smart list you want to hide, remember you need to find the list ID for each list and replace the XXXXX for each one.